# Python for loop invalid syntax (Replacing contents of columns in dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for the simple question but I'm losing my mind here. From researching previous similar questions, it looks like I have to look at the line before to correct this. However, my code before is fine, in fact adding the for loop introduces the error.

Basically I want to loop my data frame list and replace the contents of the first column (Column name = BOL) with the value BLS. (Data frame 1 column gets BLS 1, and Data frame 2 column gets BLS 2, etc...)

Below is the error and the code.

> File "ex2.py", line 41
>       for x in BLS
>                  ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

def df_style(val):
              return 'font-weight: bold'

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

BLS = list(map(str, input("Please enter the BL#'s: ").split())) 
print("BL#'s: ", BLS)

files = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
print("--------------")
print(files)
ExcelFileNames = [Path(x).name for x in files]
print("--------------")
print(type(ExcelFileNames))
print("--------------")
print(ExcelFileNames)
print("--------------")
print (ExcelFileNames[0])
print("--------------")
print("Number of files is:", len(ExcelFileNames))
print("--------------")
# read them in
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in files]


# turn them into dataframes
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None, skiprows=4) for x in excels]
print(type(frames))
print("--------------")

# delete the first row for all frames except the first
# i.e. remove the header row -- assumes it's the first
frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

for x in BLS
    print(x)
    frames[x].BOL = BLS
# this prints the first row of the first data frame -  print(frames[0].iloc[0])
# concatenate them..
combined = pd.concat(frames)


# write it out
combined.to_excel("DNcombined.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: You missed a colon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a colon in this section:

```
for x in BLS
    print(x)
    frames[x].BOL = BLS
```

It should look like this:

```
for x in BLS:
    print(x)
    frames[x].BOL = BLS
```